# Selecting specific row number in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is any way that I could select specified number of rows in SQL Server? Like on my first query, I wanted to get rows 1-5, then next is rows 6-10, then onwards? Thank you in advance for your answers :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

For SQL Server 2005+ (set @startRow and @endRow):

```
SELECT OrderingColumn 
FROM (
    SELECT OrderingColumn, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY OrderingColumn) AS RowNum
    FROM MyTable
) AS MyDerivedTable
WHERE MyDerivedTable.RowNum BETWEEN @startRow and @endRow
```

SQL fiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b4b8c/4

Comment: Hi! Your code works! Thank you very much! But it is possible to do multiple of this in one query? Three different columns with different startrow and endrow just from one table in one query?
It looks like this:

C1   |C2    |C3
aa   |bb    |cc
dd   |ee    |ff
gg   |hh

Comment: @Brenelyn No worries. About your question: Why would you to have different start- and endrows? Can you elaborate in another question and then paste the link here, please?

Comment: I discussed here want I wanted to do. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17269078/subquery-returns-more-than-1-value-sql-error-on-multiple-selection)

Comment: How can we add this output into a temp table? If I append  `into #temp` after this, i get syntax error.

Comment: @RossCooper probably you missed to declare the temp table before the select?
create table #temp
( Col1 INT, Col2 INT )

Comment: syntax error is in "into". While doing into, I don't thinks it's needed to declare a temp table. In fact if you do that, it shows an error.

Answer (score 9):

For SQL Server 2012, try this (simply set the offset)

```
SELECT  *
FROM     MyTable 
ORDER BY OrderingColumn ASC 
OFFSET  0 ROWS 
FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY
```

`OFFSET`:
Specifies the number of rows to skip before it starts to return rows from the query expression.

`FETCH NEXT`:
Specifies the number of rows to return after the `OFFSET` clause has been processed.

Definitions of `OFFSET` and `FETCH NEXT` are from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx).

Query 1:
Offset 0 => 1-5

Query 2:
Offset 5 => 6-10, etc.

SQL fiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b4b8c/2

Comment: **SQL** = query language, **SQL Server** = Microsoft RDBMS product

Comment: Thank you very much! Sorry I don't know what to call that so sorry for having it duplicated to other questions :)

Comment: @Brenelyn No problem. Just make sure to set the offset according to your current page.
Query 1 => Offset 0
Query 2 => Offset 5
etc.

Comment: this is a 2012 feature, right?

Comment: @momobo unfortunately, yes this is only for 2012. I also added another answer for SQL 2005 (using row_number)