# Subquery returns more than 1 value SQL error on multiple selection

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, select, insert

I wanted to have a temporary table that will insert values using select statements. But every time I ran the query, I always got error

> Subquery returns more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the query follows =, !=, <, <=, >, >=, or when the subquery is used as an expression. The statement has been terminated. (0 row(s) affected)

It's weird cause it seems there's no errors in the code. But if there is, please correct me.

Here's the query:

```
DECLARE @tblKeywords TABLE (Keyword1 VARCHAR(MAX), Keyword2 VARCHAR(MAX), Keyword3 VARCHAR(MAX))

Insert into @tblKeywords (Keyword1, Keyword2, Keyword3)
Values(
(Select k from 
(Select Keyword k, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY KeywordID) AS RowNum from t_SMSKeyword) as mytable
where mytable.RowNum BETWEEN 1 and 3),

(Select kk from 
(Select Keyword kk, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY KeywordID) AS RowNum from t_SMSKeyword) as mytable
where mytable.RowNum BETWEEN 4 and 6),

(Select kkk from 
(Select Keyword kkk, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY KeywordID) AS RowNum from t_SMSKeyword) as mytable
where mytable.RowNum BETWEEN 7 and 9)
)

Select * from @tblKeywords
```

Comment: Have you fired Subqueries separately? If yes then what was rowcount for each subquery?

Comment: @Brenelyn : You have three sub-queries. One or more of these return more than one row. So arises the problem. Try running each subquery separately, you will find the problem.

Comment: It works fine when I ran the queries separately. But I want to get the results in just one query so I can put them in asp:gridview.

Comment: when you have between 1 and 3 for example that gives you three rows and not one. Do you think you need to add TOP 1?

Comment: @Edper, yes, it gives me three rows.

Comment: @Brenelyn but you need one only right which is for KeyWord1, because 4 to 6 would go to KeyWord2 and 7 to 9 to KeyWord3?

Comment: @Edper, Yes! for column Keyword1, I was to get rows 1 - 3, then for column Keyword2 are rows 4 - 6 then so on. The original table is all of the data are returned only from one column, and I wanted to group the data into 3 then allocate them into 3 different columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQLServer2005+ You can use option with [common table expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

```
DECLARE @tblKeywords TABLE (Keyword1 VARCHAR(MAX), Keyword2 VARCHAR(MAX), Keyword3 VARCHAR(MAX))

;WITH cte AS
 (      
  SELECT Keyword, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY KeywordID) AS RowNum       
  FROM dbo.t_SMSKeyword  
  )
  INSERT @tblKeywords(Keyword1, Keyword2, Keyword3)
  SELECT c1.Keyword, c2.Keyword, c3.Keyword
  FROM cte c1 JOIN cte c2 ON c1.RowNum + 3 = c2.RowNum
              JOIN cte c3 ON c2.RowNum + 3 = c3.RowNum
  WHERE c1.RowNum BETWEEN 1 and 3
```

See example on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/898bc/1)

Select 4 rows in the first column and 3 rows for the other columns

```
DECLARE @tblKeywords TABLE (Keyword1 VARCHAR(MAX), Keyword2 VARCHAR(MAX), Keyword3 VARCHAR(MAX))
;WITH cte AS
 (      
  SELECT Keyword, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY KeywordID) AS RowNum       
  FROM dbo.t_SMSKeyword  
  )
  INSERT @tblKeywords(Keyword1, Keyword2, Keyword3)
  SELECT c1.Keyword, c2.Keyword, c3.Keyword
  FROM cte c1 LEFT JOIN cte c2 ON c1.RowNum + 4 = c2.RowNum AND c2.RowNum < 8
              LEFT JOIN cte c3 ON c2.RowNum + 3 = c3.RowNum
  WHERE c1.RowNum BETWEEN 1 and 4

SELECT *
FROM @tblKeywords
```

Example for second solution [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5c811/1)

Comment: thanks! It works perfectly.. but may I ask if it's possible to select 4 rows in the first column then 3 rows for the other columns? Thank you again :)

Answer (score 0):

You'll get your desired result with the following query

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3d528/3)

```
DECLARE @tblKeywords TABLE (Keyword1 VARCHAR(MAX), Keyword2 VARCHAR(MAX), Keyword3 VARCHAR(MAX))

Insert into @tblKeywords (Keyword1, Keyword2, Keyword3)
 select k,kk,kkk from 
(Select k, RowNum from 
(Select Keyword k, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY KeywordID) AS RowNum from t_SMSKeyword) as mytable
where mytable.RowNum BETWEEN 1 and 3) a,

(Select kk, RowNum from 
(Select Keyword kk, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY KeywordID) AS RowNum from t_SMSKeyword) as mytable
where mytable.RowNum BETWEEN 4 and 6) b,

(Select kkk,RowNum from 
(Select Keyword kkk, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY KeywordID) AS RowNum from t_SMSKeyword) as mytable
where mytable.RowNum BETWEEN 7 and 9) c

where a.RowNum = b.RowNum-3
and a.RowNum = c.RowNum-6;

Select * from @tblKeywords;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
DECLARE @tblKeywords TABLE
    (
      Keyword1 VARCHAR(MAX) ,
      Keyword2 VARCHAR(MAX) ,
      Keyword3 VARCHAR(MAX)
    )

INSERT  INTO @tblKeywords
        ( Keyword1 ,
          Keyword2 ,
          Keyword3
        )
        SELECT  k ,
                ( SELECT    kk
                  FROM      ( SELECT    e.Keyword AS kk ,
                                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY e.KeywordID ) AS RowNum1
                              FROM      t_SMSKeyword AS e
                            ) AS Emp1
                  WHERE     Emp1.RowNum1 = ( RowNum + 3 )
                ) ,
                ( SELECT    kkk
                  FROM      ( SELECT    e.Keyword AS kkk ,
                                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY e.KeywordID ) AS RowNum1
                              FROM      t_SMSKeyword AS e
                            ) AS Emp1
                  WHERE     Emp1.RowNum1 = ( RowNum + 6 )
                )
        FROM    ( SELECT    e.Keyword AS k ,
                            ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY e.KeywordID ) AS RowNum
                  FROM      t_SMSKeyword AS e
                ) AS mytable
        WHERE   mytable.RowNum BETWEEN 1 AND 3







SELECT  *
FROM    @tblKeywords
```