# how to use rownumber to write a paging query in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know how to use the "select top" to write a paging query, but I don't know how to write it using rownumber. 
Who can tell me? Thank you!

Comment: It was the first result of 'sql server rownumber paging'.  You're welcome.

Comment: Check out my answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17259716/selecting-specific-row-number-in-sql/17259963#17259963

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select * from (
    select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by SalesOrderDate desc) as rn, *
    from sales.salesorderheader
) as x
where rn between @start and @start + @page_size
```

That ought to do the trick.

Comment: but he wants to pass the order by as a parameter

Comment: @Hogan - How do you discern that? Can't see any mention of that in the question body or title.

Comment: Wat? Not sure how dynamic order by made it into " know how to use the "select top" to write a paging query, but I don't know how to write it using rownumber. Who can tell me? Thank you!"

Comment: @MartinSmith - My point is that is always the next question in this case, and this topic (and all the variations) has been covered on SO for years.  This is a duplicate.

Comment: @MartinSmith - in fact you have a much better answer right here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620758/t-sql-skip-take-stored-procedure -- I upvoted it... it was really good.

Comment: In fact, I want to test whether I can express my question well in English. My native language isn't English. This is my fisrt time here -- a good place to solve coding problems. I'll visit here often. Thank you all.

Comment: Careful, between will include extremes so it will return $page_size + 1 records instead of $page_size.Only when start = 0 will return $page_size records. So it's better if where condition is: `where rn > $start and rn <= ($start + $page_size)`.

Answer (score -3):

Try following generalize query :

```
DECLARE @Start INT = 0
DECLARE @page_size INT = 10
DECLARE @Orderby VARCHAR(max) = 'SalesOrderDate'
DECLARE @Order VARCHAR(max) = 'desc';

WITH temp
     AS (SELECT case when 'SalesOrderDate' then ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SalesOrderDate) 
                                            ELSE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) END AS rn,
                *
         FROM   sales.salesorderheader)
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT row_number() OVER(ORDER BY CASE 
                                          WHEN @Order = 'asc' 
                                          THEN rn 
                                          ELSE -rn 
                                          END) AS finalorder,
               *
        FROM   temp) AS x
WHERE  finalorder BETWEEN @start AND @start + @page_size
```

Comment: This answer is horrible.

Comment: `SalesOrderDate` and `id` are highly unlikely to be the same datatype. If `Date` and `int` this won't work (and it won't be able to use any indexes to avoid a sort)

Comment: @Hiren Dhaduk -- as Martin says the best way is an IF statement

Comment: no , I found more generalize solution. let me modify my answer .

Comment: Check it we used this type of query in one of our project . it will work properly.

Comment: @martin check my ans i solved that data type mismatch problem .